# How is Sophia going to reset history in Full Metal Panic?

Tags: full-metal-panic

Sophia claims that she can reset history by using TARTAROS, but what is the mechanism of doing so, does the Tau wave have reality bending ability?

Doesn't the Tau wave just allow you to peek the future?

Answer (score 1):

The TAROS more or less is the reason the Tau waves cover the planet after the incident at Yamsk 11 that started it all on Dec. 24, 1981 (1984 in the anime). The waves exist outside time and on all planes of existence.

Sophia was present in the very first TAROS incident at Yamsk 11. She is more or less the reason why Whispered can resonate with one another.

> On that faithful day, Sophia died, but her consciousness merged with the Tau waves, somehow...

Because Tau waves exist outside time and space, there is a degree of time manipulation allowed by it.

Sophia's consciousness exists where ever and whenever Tau waves are present. Sophia can send her consciousness into the future to gain the technology that she then shares with the Whispered.

She is not a Whispered, but rather the one doing the whispering. The reason why Whispered have specializations is because her consciousness is split between them all. Only Sophia existed from the very start of it all so only she had the means and circumstances to be able to go back to when it first started.